# PYTHON: How to override "Runtime error" and call multiple function in sequence

Tags: python, pandas, function, runtime, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a dataset from a GitHub. To make it simple, the program starts like this:

```
def main(): 
 df=pd.read_json('url')
 dati=[]
 dati_giornalieri=list(df.nuovi_positivi)
 u=len(dati_giornalieri)

 for i in range(u-60,u):
 dati.append('0')
 dati[i-u+60]=dati_giornalieri[i]  #here it takes some values and it lists them.
 stage1(dati)
```

Now I have an array/list of 60 values (dati) and I pass them to the fitting function (stage1) which passes the y data (the 60 values) to curvefit (the x data are simply [1,2,3...]:

```
def objective2(x, a1, b1, c1,t1, a2, b2, c2,t2):
   return y=a1*(x**2)+b1*x+c1+ a2+b2+c2+t2

def stage1(data):
 
 #some code

 popt, _ = curve_fit(objective2, xData, yData, maxfev=100000)

 #here I wrote some lines that makes possibile to plot the curve and the data

 pyplot.show()
```

Now the problem. To fit the 60 data sometimes the function "stage1" works but sometimes that function doesn't work. The program exits (like a crash) and usually get the message

```
RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 100000.
```

I perfectly know why this happens: the chosen curve is not ok to fit data so I prepared another function in the code:

```
    def objective3(x, a1, b1, c1,t1, a2, b2, c2,t2):
     return y=a1*(x**3)+b1*(x**2)+c1*x+ a2+b2+c2+t2 #different from the former

    def stage2(data):
     #some code

     popt, _ = curve_fit(objective3, xData, yData, maxfev=100000)

     #here I wrote some lines that makes possibile to plot the curve and the data

     pyplot.show()
```

and again this function may work or we can get the same "Runtime error", again because the curve is not good to fit the data.

I prepared 10 functions and in my experience at least one always does the trick, making the desired plot, but the problem is that I have to "manually tell" the code what function to select to get the desired result (plot).

How can I "tell" the program to try ALL "stage functions", i.e. stage1(dati), stage2(dati) etc... and plot ALL the ones that doesn't raise runtime error?

I tried calling all function at the same time (in main function)

```
stage1(dati)
stage2(dati)
stage3(dati)
...
```

but if stage1 raises the error then the program exits and stage2(dati) isn't read at all.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the solution is twofold in your case. First off, the most logical thing to do in programming land is to only work with data that is valid. So if possible, skip entries from which you know they won't get handled. Secondly, if you get an error and it is a consistent error, try calling with try-except and catch that specified error. The error will then still occur, but at least you can opt to ignore it instead of letting the program crash. Be warned, this might not result into the desired outcome.

Comment: Maybe I explained myself not well. The problem is NOT the error (that is perfectly sound in the code) but that a-priori I don't know if the selected function (stage1 or stage2 etc.) is the right one since the 60-value dataset is highy variable. Suppose fo instance that the 60-value are more or less in line. Ok the proper function is y=ax+b. Suppose passes a month. Now the 60-value is an exponential. Ok the proper function is now y=exp(x), and so y=ax+b doesn't fit well, maybe it gives runtime error. I want that the code outputs the y=exp(x) plot and not y=ax+b, it has to ignore runtime error

Comment: And the question could be: how can I try-except a runtime error? It's ok to do try-except with numbers or strings but how to do with curvefit?